# How to store register value in variable ARM7

Tags: assembly, arm, arm7

I'm trying to write a program to store the larger of two values in the variable `larger`

I'm new to ARM7 and am having trouble figuring out how to store the values in my registers to that label variable.

Heres my code with the errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its a convoluted solution, but when using a RISC processor, you have to cope with certain things.

Basically this solution works by storing the address of the variable in a register, and then  using that register to change the value.
[image]